# Suppress Xcode incompatible pointer type for subclass of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a subclass of UIViewController called SurveyQuestion. I use an array of these for my app. I get the currently visible controller with this line:

```
SurveyQuestion *currentQuestionController = [self.navigationController visibleViewController];
```

Everything works, but Xcode gives me a warning of

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SurveyQuestion *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'
```

I know this is because visibleViewController returns a UIViewController, but it works because SurveyQuestion IS a UIViewController. Is there any way to suppress this error? Or should I be doing it a different way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use cast like

```
SurveyQuestion *currentQuestionController = (SurveyQuestion *)[self.navigationController visibleViewController];
```

Comment: duh, I was definitely over thinking it